# Can the word 'aggregation' be used to mean a collection of people?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm wondering if one can use the word "aggregation" to mean a *team* or a *collaboration* of sorts, or even a certain collection of individuals in general, not just objects. Any thoughts?

Comment: **Cohort** can be a useful word here, particularly in statistical discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Aggregation* can certainly be used to mean a collection of individuals.

I will note that, in my mind at least, *aggregation* tends to imply a level of disorganization or heterogeneity that I think somewhat conflicts with the idea of a formalized team.  So, while it works well for an ad hoc collaboration working towards a particular end, I probably wouldn't use it for a group that is otherwise already entangled.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, yes.

Here's one of the definitions according to the OED:

> **4.** *concr*. A whole composed of many particulars; a mass formed by the
>   union of distinct particles; a
>   gathering, assemblage, collection.

And from the quotations:

> **1638** Chillingworth *Relig. Prot.* i. ii. §142. 107 The Church being nothing else but an aggregation of Believers.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no.

While *aggregation* can **technically** be used to describe a group of individuals, in common modern usage it only describes a group of objects.

Simon Jester's second example shows a usage of the word that has generally gone out of style.

Language is an ever-evolving animal, and majority usage rules – even if the dictionary tells you otherwise.  Dictionaries are outdated almost the moment they are published, especially in this day and age. (Opinion)

If you must use *aggregation* to describe a group of individuals, try focusing on a quality (i.e. object) that the group shares, e.g.

> ... an aggregation of the writers' skills.